# Cost Calculator

Tags: java, arrays

My code needs to calculate the cost of ISP service via 3 different questions.
choice of package (1,2,3)
Which month it is: (1-12)
How many hours used:(x)

I broke the months into 3 separate arrays. One for Feb. with 28 days, one for months with 30 days and one with months that have 31 days. I need to check the number of hours entered and make sure that it does not exceed the amount of hours that are in whichever month they have chosen. I have started to with this:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Needed for the scanner class

public class ISP_Cost_Calc 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String input;                                   //To hold users input.
        char selectPackage;                             //To hold Internet Package
        double hourUsage, totalCharges, addCharges;     //Variables 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      //Create a Scanner object to collect keyboard input.

        int[] twentyeightArray;                         //List of months with 28 days (that's what the te is for)
        twentyeightArray = new int[1];                  //Make room for one integer in list
        twentyeightArray[0] = 2;                        //Set the one integer in this list to month number 2

        int[] thirtyArray;                              //List of months with 30 days.
        thirtyArray = new int[4];
        thirtyArray[0] = 4;
        thirtyArray[1] = 6;
        thirtyArray[2] = 9;
        thirtyArray[3] = 11;

        int[] thiryoneArray;                                //List of months with 31 days.
        thiryoneArray = new int[7];
        thiryoneArray[0] = 1;
        thiryoneArray[1] = 3;                               
        thiryoneArray[2] = 5;
        thiryoneArray[3] = 7;
        thiryoneArray[4] = 8;
        thiryoneArray[5] = 10;
        thiryoneArray[6] = 12;


        //Prompt the user to select a Internet Package.
        System.out.print("Enter your plan (1, 2, 3):");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        selectPackage = input.charAt(0);
        //Prompt the user for the month.
        System.out.print("Enter your month number (1-12):");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        char monthNum = input.charAt(0);
        //Prompt the user for how many hours used.
        System.out.print("Enter your hours:");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        hourUsage = Double.parseDouble(input);

//Display pricing for selected package...

            switch (selectPackage)
            {

                case '1':
                    if (hourUsage > 10)
                    {
                        addCharges = hourUsage - 10;
                        totalCharges = (addCharges * 2.0) + 9.95;
                        System.out.println("You have used " + hourUsage + " hours and your total is $" + totalCharges + " per month. ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Your total is $9.95 per month.");

                    }
                    break;


                case '2':
                    if (hourUsage > 20 )
                    { 
                        addCharges = hourUsage - 20;
                        totalCharges = (addCharges * 1.0) + 13.95;
                        System.out.println("You have used " + hourUsage + " and your total is $" + totalCharges + " per month.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Your total is $13.95 per month.");

                    }
                    break;


                case '3':
                    System.out.println("Your total is $19.95 per month.");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Choice.");
            }

    }


}
```

So I just need advice with how to incorporate this into my if statements.
Thank you

Comment: How to incorporate what into your if statements?

Comment: Um, everything I stated in the begging of my question about the months...?

Comment: do you want to incorporate the conditions based on your month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using separate arrays to implement your month. You can do this:

```
int[] month = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
int[] monthLeapYear = {31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
```

You can check whether a given year is a leap year first, then choose the right array to use for the month. This way you only need 2 arrays - ever.

and you may have something like this to help you. I also advise you to create some methods in your implementation to modularize your program.

```
public static Boolean isLeapYear(int year)
{
    if(year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)
        return true; 
    return false;   
}
```

---

The array is by index `0 - 11`. That be can be over come by doing this:

```
//Let say your current month is 1-12
month[currentMonth-1]
```

**Alternatively** add 1 element to your array (so that the elements tally now):

```
int[] month = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
```

Comment: Ok, I like this. Only question I have is since this list of months is 0-11, how do I make it so I can have the user choose months 1-12?

Comment: @MIKED As explained above. Don't worry that this don't look elegant, I've seen actual commercial product doing this kind of implementation as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's only my first assignment learning java so I just want to get a working program haha.

Comment: I just tried to do so! I do not have the required reputation(15) to up-vote yet. The day I get 15 I will return to this problem and give you the vote you deserve!

Comment: @MIKED Yes, but you still can accept answer here by clicking the tick (below upvote/downvote buttons). Not the upvote button. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier if instead of using seperatre arrays for different numbers of days, you use an enum of Months which contains the number of days and the number of hours.

```
public enum Month {

JANUARY(31),FEBRUARY(28),MARCH(31),APRIL(30),MAY(31),JUNE(30),JULY(31),AUGUST(30),SEPTEMBER(30),OCTOBER(31),
NOVEMBER(30),DECEMBER(31);

private int hours;
private Month(int days){
    hours = days*24;
}

public int getHours(){
    return hours;
}
```

}

Using something like that would cut down on the unnecessary array use and combine everything into a single class.  This would make it a lot easier to get the number of days and hours in each month.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple arrays, just use one array like:

```
month[0] = 31;
month[1] = 28;//what if leap year?
month[2] = 31;
//and so on
```

Then you could do something like:

```
int monthNumber = monthNum - 48;
if (hours > month[monthNumber - 1] * 24) {
    //do something
} else {
     //else do another thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is insane.

What is going to happen in 2016 when February will have 29 days instead of 28 days?

Stop using integers to represent hours.  Use proper data types like DateTime and TimeSpan.

Get the DateTime at 00:00 of the 1st day of the selected month, 
then get the DateTime at 00:00 of the 1st day of the next month,
then calculate the difference of these two to obtain a TimeSpan holding the duration of the selected month.

Then convert your hours to a TimeSpan and compare this against the duration of the selected month.

This will tell you whether the entered number of hours fits within the selected month.

Comment: Yes, I am aware there are leap years lol. It's not in the scope of the problem I was handed. This is the first assignment of the year in my java class. We are also supposed to use what we have covered in class up till now. so DateTime and TimeSpan would probably be great, but I'm not going to use it.

Comment: `so DateTime and TimeSpan would probably be great, but I'm not going to use it.`.. Who uses proper ways to do things anymore..?

Answer (score 0):

To check conditions based on your months.You can use contains method of arraylist by converting array into arraylist as

```
Arrays.asList(your1stArray).contains(yourChar)
```

in your char just add the input no of the month 
for eg:

```
  switch (monthNum )
        {

            case '1':
                if (Arrays.asList(your1stArray).contains(yourChar)){
    //code goes here
}
    case '1':
                if (Arrays.asList(your2ndArray).contains(yourChar)){
    //code goes here
}

)
)
```